# Certain Emails Get Deleted In Outlook When Opening

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2007

We are running Exchange 2003 R2 and we have several users where only certain emails go into the hard delete bin.  However, it is sporadic and doesn't happen all the time.  It doesn't matter if the email is from an internal user or outside the company.

Some are using outlook 2003 and others are on 2007.  They all have some sort of smart phone that they use to check emails with.  Some have blackberries and palm treos.  However, we don't have a blackberry server.  We just use the cell phone provider's forwarding feature.

Here is what I’ve done so far for further troubleshooting.

1. I set up the users email profile on a different machine and a different version of outlook and it still did it.
2. I deleted their user account, recreated and remounted their mailbox on the exchange server
3. I called Verizon and they had me do a hard reset on the cell phone and reconfigured exchange ACTIVE SYNC

One thing that I did discover during this, was that if I have outlook closed it works fine and the email never gets deleted when on the phone.  However, AS SOON as I open Outlook up it never shows up in the inbox and then it disappears on the cell phone just like magic!

Now if you check the hard deleted bin by going through OWA, it shows up in there!  So for some reason something is deleting it and placing it in the hard deleted bin.  This is happening on a handful of people in our office.

Can't seem to figure this out.  HELP!

Answer (score 2):

Is Outlook connecting via POP3 or IMAP? If the former, is it set to delete upon retrieval? If so that would account for what you are seeing.